# Flexbox и IE9-10

Tags: css3, html5, internet-explorer, flexbox, crossbrowsertesting

Всем привет!

При верстке  сайта  частично использовался flexbox, и тут заказчик заявил, что  нужно  еще и поддержка IE9-10.

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Во-первых, быстро-срочно переделывайте на не-flexbox? Во-вторых, всё это должно обговариваться заранее и желательно в письменной форме, если такого не было — советую отправлять таких заказчиков куда подальше

Comment: Как говорится: `Нет ТЗ? Результат - ХЗ` человек выше всё правильно сказал. И вообще нужно всегда в письменной форме заверять что конкретно нужно от проекта, какие цели стоят, что должно быть реализовано. Если нет возможности / желания составлять договоры - то требуйте от заказчика всегда заранее ТЗ хотя бы в виде письма/одного сообщения в ЛС, задавайте вопросы и предупреждайте о доп. сроках и доп. оплате в случае выхода за рамки ТЗ

Comment: @ScreamingVoices Ваш комментарий   стал  наиболее полезным, спасибо!
А фразу нет ТЗ?  результат - ХЗ я взял  на вооружение :)

Comment: IE10 поддерживает flex. Можно начать с автопрефиксера. А вот 9й - нет.

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83/5264#5264)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать полифилы. К примеру этот: https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility

Подробнее про полифилы: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Полифил](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB)